# Error:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

Tengo un error al escribir esto en mi buil.gradle de mi modulo volley que importe:

> useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Un vez que escribo esa linea y sincronizo el proyecto nuevamente me muestra este error:

> Error:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Estoy usando la libreria volley, este es el **buil.gradle** de el modulo volley:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.sherter.google-java-format" version "0.6"
    id "net.ltgt.errorprone" version "0.0.13"
}

googleJavaFormat {
    toolVersion = '1.5'
    options style: 'AOSP'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

group = 'com.android.volley'
version = '1.1.1-SNAPSHOT'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

apply from: 'rules.gradle'
apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

Este es mi **Module: app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_planp_enrique_espinosa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Y por ultimo mi **buil.gradle**:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
 to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {

     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
     } }

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
     } }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿para qué quieres agregar `'org.apache.http.legacy'`?  Si es para las peticiones HTTP no la necesitas, si optas por `Volley`

Comment: @A.Cedano si de echo quiero hacer una aplicacion que use un web service y hacer peticiones como GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, tenia entendido que se necesitaba para que pudiera funcionar.

Comment: No, todo eso lo puedes hacer con `Volley`. Pero usa la biblioteca `Volley` oficial de Android, pues hay una que no es la oficial y que además es obsoleta.

Comment: Yo estoy usando esta, la baje desde el sitio de Android Developer
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Esa misma. Con ella, no necesitas a `org.apache.http.legacy`. Pero ten en cuenta que el código con `Volley` no se escribe como en la otra librería... es mucho más simple, pero es preciso que entiendas cómo funciona. Encontrarás varios ejemplos aquí y en la red.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Es importante mencionar que las [librerías Apache están marcadas como obsoletas](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html?hl=es-419#behavior-apache-http-client), esto para Android 6.0 (API 23) o posterior

Para continuar utilizandolas debes activar el "modo legacy" en tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
    ...
}
```

pero hay algo importante si estas definiendo:

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
```

y

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

en realidad ya no existe la opción de soporte o legacy, para "solucionar" esto debes cambiar a maximo :

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

En realidad la solución correcta es cambiar a **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)** o usar una versión actualizada de `Volley`, ya que no es buena idea bajar el nivel de la API.

En el sitio tenemos varios ejemplos del uso de esta Clase:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=httpurlconnection

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.